# Karlin-Rubin shows $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta >\theta_0$ is UMP, what about $H_0: \theta \geq \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta <\theta_0$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

The Karlin-Rubin Test gives conditions where the test $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta >\theta_0$ is UMP, I am wondering what we can do in cases where $H_0: \theta \geq \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta <\theta_0$? In this case do we just invert the test?

Comment: Consider a reparameterization from $\theta$ to $\phi=-\theta$, apply the same theorem to $\phi$, take the test back to the equivalent test in $\theta$ (i.e. translate the rejection rule to give a rejection region in terms of $\theta$, which must reject the same part of the sample space), and you get the second inequality.

Comment: Usually H0 represents the null hypothesis and H1 the alternative.  Even if you don't want to use that that notation H0 can't be both the null and alternative hypothesis.